# child component update parent component

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate

I just wonder if it is good that the child component updates the parent component.
in the source code, like following

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  state = {
    name : ''
  }
  changeState = ((state) => {
    this.setState(state)
  })
  submit = (() => {
    // send state to api..
  })
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Child changeState={this.changeState} {...this.state}/>
        <button onClick={this.submit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}



class Child extends React.Component{
  change = ((e) => {
    this.props.changeState({
      name : e.target.value
    })
  })
  render(){
    return(
      <input onChange={this.change} value={this.props.name} />
    )
  }
}
```

the reason I use this way is submitting method.
There are many input tags, and I want to bind them all together.

but I'm not sure this way is good or not.
because when I type something, parent component always will rerender.
I think it is not good.(actually it just my thinking...)
is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this way to update state of a parent from a child. It does work properly. But it makes the components little complex.

In your case (assuming you do this for text input elements) I don't think this will be a good practice if you are doing it for tiny input components. Because every time you hit a key on a keyboard the parent component will try to update.

But if you are wrapping a set of input elements and pass a larger object to a parent component I think that will be fine.

You could use react life cycle method shouldComponentUpdate() method to control the rendering of the parent component

shouldComponentUpdate
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.props.name != nextProps.name) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Here nextProps refers to the props you receive(updates) and you can refer to current prop values by "this.props"

And return true to render and false to skip the rendering.

Comment: can I get example to use shouldComponent in my code?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Here nextProps refers to the props you receive(updates) and you can refer to current prop values by "this.props"

Answer (score 2):

If you have perform validations when the user inputs, then its ok.
Otherwise change 'onChange' event to 'onBlur'

Answer (score 2):

Its a good idea to lift the state up and update it in the parent if multiple other siblings want to refer to the same values. You can optimise on this my making your Parent and Child Components pure as long as they don't have complex and deeply nested props and states.

According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent):

> `React.PureComponent` is exactly like `React.Component`, but
>   implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` with a shallow prop and state
>   comparison. If your React component’s render() function renders the
>   same result given the same props and state, you can use
>   `React.PureComponent` for a performance boost in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Re-rendering of parent is not a problem as long as it is not wasted. And Unless you are using Redux, I think this is a proper way to manage the state, i.e., inside the parent component and updating it using the child. In this way, you have made your form into a [controlled component](https://lorenstewart.me/2016/10/31/react-js-forms-controlled-components/).
I think the following page will be useful to you: https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-react/parent-child-component-communication